# Implementing 1/mean function in R

Tags: r, function, statistics

I have to simulate the sampling distribution of 1/Xbar when sampling from a normal population. I just want to know if I started my code out right since everything else depends on this.

```
MC <- 10000 # Number of samples to simulate

sampling.tau <- function(mu, sigma, sampleSize, MC) {
  tau_hat = c(1:MC)
  for(i in 1:MC)
  {
    mySample <- rnorm(n=sampleSize, mean=mu, sd=sigma)
    tau_hat[i] <- 1/mean(mySample)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note, there's no need in `c(1:MC)`, use just `1:MC`, this is already a single vector. Second note, you do not return `tau_hat`. Third note, declaring `tau_hat <- numeric(MC)` is probably a better way: you are overwriting it anyway.

Apart from that, everything looks good. I'd modify your code a bit to avoid looping:

```
sampling.tau.2 <- function(mu, sigma, sampleSize, MC) {
  replicate(MC, 1/mean(rnorm(sampleSize, mu, sigma)))
}

sampling.tau.2(10, 1, 100, 5)
# values should be close to 1/mu = 1/10
[1] 0.09808410 0.10000718 0.09870573 0.09952546 0.09843164
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you are on the right track. Here is a way to confirm it.

If `X` is a random variable distributed as N(μ,σ<sup>2</sup>), and `Y`is a random variable formed as the mean of `X` (e.g., the sum of n independent samples of X, divided by n), then

> X ~ N(μ,σ<sup>2</sup>)
>
> Y ~ N(μ,σ<sup>2</sup>/n)

You want samples from the distribution of `Z = 1/Y`. In general, if the density function for `Y` is given by

> Prob(y ≤ Y ≤ y+dy) ≡ f<sub>Y</sub>(y), then, if Z = 1/Y
>
> Prob(z ≤ Z ≤ z+dz) ≡ f<sub>Z</sub>(z) = (1/z<sup>2</sup>) × f<sub>Y</sub>(1/z)

Since

> f<sub>Y</sub>(y) = √(n/2π) × (1/σ) × exp[-n × (y - μ)<sup>2</sup>/2σ<sup>2</sup>]
>
> f<sub>Z</sub>(z) = (1/z<sup>2</sup>) × 1/√2π × (n/√σ) × exp[-n × (1/z - μ)<sup>2</sup>/2σ<sup>2</sup>]

So the question is: does your code produce random samples distributed as `Z`? The answer can be shown to be "yes".

```
f <- function(z,n,mu=0,sigma=1) 
  (1/z^2)*sqrt(n/(2*pi))*(1/sigma)*exp(-(1/z-mu)^2*(n/(2*sigma^2)))

g <- function(mu, sigma, sampleSize, MC)
  replicate(MC, 1/mean(rnorm(sampleSize, mu, sigma)))

set.seed(1)
hist(g(0,0.1,100,1000),breaks=c(-Inf,seq(-300,300,10),Inf)
     ,xlim=c(-300,300), xlab = "Z",
     main="Histogram of 1/mean(X)", sub="mu=0, sigma=0.1, n=100")
z <- seq(-300,300,1)
lines(z,f(z,100,mu=0,sigma=.1),col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the sampling distribution of `1/mean(X)` where `X` is Normal you can save yourself a **lot** of time by recognizing that if `X` has mean `mu`, sd `sigma`, then the sampling distribution of the mean of `N` samples is Normal with mean `mu` and sd `sigma/sqrt(N)`, so:

```
sampling.tau.3 <- function(mu, sigma, sampleSize, MC) {
   1/rnorm(MC, mu, sigma/sqrt(sampleSize))
}
```

should be *much* faster and give comparable results (you should obviously double-check it against the brute-force solutions for yourself ...)